# Changing RewriteRule with 2 different URLs conditions in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quality\%20time.php?id=$1&kategori=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /view.php?id=$1&judul=$2 [L]
```

My plan is to convert the 2 conditions, :

```
http://jatengtravelguide.com/quality%20time.php?id=6
change to : http://jatengtravelguide.com/6/QUALITY%20TIME.html
```

The first change successfully, but i can't change for second condition:

```
http://jatengtravelguide.com/view.php?id=111&judul=Bubur%20Ayam%20Mang%20Dudung
change to: http://jatengtravelguide.com/111/Bubur%20Ayam%20Mang%20Dudung.html
```

But when I investigated, the wrong pages are displayed.  Instead of `view.php`, `quality time.php` pages are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$
```

with **L** flag make redirect be done. So when first condition be true it would be run. Second condition could be run when previous conditions are not be true.

Comment: can u help me for solution?

Comment: If you use `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.htm$ /view.php?id=$1&judul=$2 [L]` and have `http://jatengtravelguide.com/111/Bubur%20Ayam%20Mang%20Dudung.htm` problem would be solved. Both condition are same in your codes. Your pathern must be different for diffferent behaviour. For example I changed html to htm for making difference.